# Laravel 5 redirect to path with parameters (not route name)

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I've been reading everywhere but couldn't find a way to redirect and include parameters in the redirection.

This method is for flash messages only so I can't use this.

```
return redirect('user/login')->with('message', 'Login Failed');
```

This method is only for routes with aliases my `routes.php` doesn't currently use an alias.

```
return redirect()->route('profile', [1]);
```

**Question 1**

Is there a way to use the path without defining the route aliases?

```
return redirect('schools/edit', compact($id));
```

When I use this approach I get this error

`InvalidArgumentException with message 'The HTTP status code "0" is not valid.'`

I have this under my routes:

```
Route::get('schools/edit/{id}', 'SchoolController@edit');
```

### Edit

Based on the [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html#method_to) the 2nd parameter is used for http status code which is why I'm getting the error above. I thought it worked like the `URL` facade wherein `URL::to('schools/edit', [$school->id])` works fine.

**Question 2**

What is the best way to approach this (without using route aliases)? Should I redirect to Controller action instead? Personally I don't like this approach seems too long for me.

I also don't like using aliases because I've already used paths in my entire application and I'm concerned it might affect the existing paths if I add an alias? No?

Comment: What kind of url do you refer to? `schools/{id}/edit` or `schools/edit?id=2`

Comment: @YoramdeLangen it's `schools/edit/{id}`

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect("schools/edit/$id");
```

or (if you prefer)

```
redirect("schools/edit/{$id}");
```

Just build the path needed.

'Naming' routes isn't going to change any URI's. It will allow you to internally reference a route via its name as opposed to having to use paths everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Did you watch the class `Illuminate\Routing\Redirector`?

You can use:

```
public function route($route, $parameters = [], $status = 302, $headers = [])
```

It depends on the route you created. If you create in your `app\Http\Routes.php` like this:

get('schools/edit/{id}', 'SchoolController@edit');

then you can create the route by:

```
redirect()->action('SchoolController@edit', compact('id'));
```

If you want to use the `route()` method you need to name your route:

```
get('schools/edit/{id}', ['as' => 'schools.edit', 'uses' => 'SchoolController@edit']);

// based on CRUD it would be:
get('schools/{id}/edit', ['as' => 'schools.edit', 'uses' => 'SchoolController@edit']);
```

[This is pretty basic.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers)

PS. If your schools controller is a resource (CRUD) based you can create a [`resource()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) and it will create the basic routes:

```
Route::resource('schools', 'SchoolController');
// or
$router->resource('schools', 'SchoolController');
```

PS. Don't forget to watch in artisan the routes you created

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I am not using `route()` because I am not using an alias `'as' => 'alias.name'`. I'm also aware of the `resource` method but I'm not using RESTful approach.

Comment: You mentioned `redirect()->action('SchoolController@edit', compact('id'));` this is what I'm trying to do but I'm using path instead. Is this achievable by `redirect('schools/edit', compact($id));` instead?

Comment: If you use `compact` as you comment right now, in this case it's not gonna work. it should be `compact('id');`

Comment: And why not using route names? Because thats the easiest solution on your question 2. Else there isn't shorter way like using the full route or by `controller@method` method. Also route names is easy for adjusting a route through your entire project.

Comment: `Also route names is easy for adjusting a route through your entire project.` Can you show how? What if I already used up 20 instances of that named route? And let's say for some random important reason that I need to change the name, how would I adjust that easily as you mentioned?

Comment: The name of the route not change, why would it change? If it should change you have a flaw in the naming.. and the name of the route should always be unique to the specific route only..
The only thing that could change is the url itself.. example: `schools/edit/{id}` to `school/edit/{id}`, but the route name could be the same `'as' => 'schools.edit'`